# where to place duplicate controller methods in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, controller

I am working on refactoring a rails 3 project. Lets say that i have controllers A, B, C and  D. Below are the methods that are reside in the controllers. Now, if we have common methods in models, we place them in module and include that module in the model. But how do we solve code repetition problem for controllers?

```
 A     B     C     D
----------------------
 m1    m1    m1
 m2    m2    m2    m2
       m3    m3
```

Here, m1, m2, m3 and m4 are some methods that are repeated in the above controllers. I dont want to move them to ApplicationController cause that will make the controller heavy and they will become global. Also, some of the method are private. Whats the ideal solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on a million things, but we'll start small. Firstly, there's no reason you can't include a module in the controller because, after all, it's just a Ruby class.

As was also briefly mentioned, you should look at why there is all this duplicated code before deciding how to clean it up. Maybe the code belongs in a helper/presenter/decorator because it has something to do with presentation logic. Maybe the code belongs in a model because it is not presentation logic but it does have to do with representing the real world.

Maybe the code does in fact belong in the ApplicationController like m2 in your example. If it's a controller-specific helper used in 4 of your controllers, the ApplicationController is probably not a bad place for it.

As you said in one of your comments, this could be as simple as placing the module in your lib directory and including it everywhere you need it. Don't forget you can also test modules (and you should) in a similar fashion:

```
class MyModuleTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  class ModuleIncluder
    include MyModule
  end

  test "some method should do a thing" do
    ... test content ...
  end
end
```

Comment: i added the methods to modules and included them in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor the common functionality into helper methods and then just call those methods from the Controller. See this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

If you have a case where the methods are exactly the same (BTW, that'd be weird and signals other problems with your code more insidious than repetition ), you can still put them into modules and include each module in your controller. Modules are a feature of the Ruby language and not the Rails framework.

Comment: so you say that m1, m2, m3 should be moved to an helper and that helper should be included in the controllers?

Comment: No,helpers are not to be included in controllers. Their methods are available to be called in Controllers.

Comment: including helpers in controller is a bad programming practice?

Comment: You don't need to. Because of the way rails is set up, they are already included in the Controller.

Comment: i think i should move them to an module in lib and include that module in controller.

Comment: Yep, that'd be one way to do it. But you should also ask yourself how did you end up in this situation where all the controllers have same code. is it the case that you have very similar models which are also displayed in the same format. If that is the case, you should be looking at presenters.